# Android App: Change Price on Google Play Developer Console (Alpha, Beta)

Tags: android, google-play

I am uploading my "Alpha/Beta" APKs and at that time can i set "Price" value to "$0.00"... and when I move from "Beta" to "Production" release at that time I will change/update price value to original price...Let's say $1.49

Is this possible - changing "Price" on Google Play Console on the basis of build/product status... (Alpha/Beta).

This will help to eliminate "Refund" process... if you are following with tester.

Any pointer on this helps - Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

You can't change the price from free (i.e. "$0.00") to non-free.  However, you can upload a separate app (like your production app) and charge for it.  In your beta app you may either want to discontinue it or add a message advertising your new paid version.

The link below is the reference:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en&ref_topic=15867

Answer (score 0):

read the legal stuff, it will tell you that once you price something as free, you can never go back. but, if you start out paid, you can change as you like unless you go free...then back to neverbackland. alpha and beta are free by design, you shouldnt charge for those.

Answer (score 0):

There's a thing called "Open Testing" that you could use to release separately multiple alpha/beta newer versions. See https://play.google.com/console/about/opentesting/

However, if you don't use that process and make the new versions replace the old one (like continuous delivery), you could have (small) periods where the app is under $0 sale for those who want to try the app in periods where it may be fragile. Problem is paid users will also get upgraded to that version and may not expect any fragility. That's why they have multiple open testing parallel tracks.

> To offer your app for $0 temporarily: Select the button next to "$0
> sale." Keep in mind, a $0 sale is temporary and is not the same as
> permanently offering your app for free.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7271135?hl=en